# What the easiest way to detect if user clicks outside a region within an Android Activity

Tags: android

I have an activity with a header, list and footer.  I want to enable search option when user touches button in header and disable as soon as they touch anywhere else but the search TextEdit in the header to enter their search criteria. I know a way to do it but I am looking for easiest and most simple approach for this, as the search header shows up on several activities.

Answer (score 1):

Make a suitable container for your elements(LinearLayout,RelativeLayout) and add all your views to it and a onClickListener for it. If the searchbutton is pressed do the usual, if the container is pressed, hide search. You might need to implement some logic if both onclick events are fired if the searchbutton is pressed.